# WP several meta_query matches, and double counted

Tags: wordpress

I set following meta_query.
I like to add one more condition.

My problem is that the article which matches both meta_query conditions are double counted by count(get_posts on the end of line.

Is it possible to add condition like this?  If both 1bb and 1aa matches, count it as if only 1bb matches.

```
<?php
$args = array(
'category_name' => $cat,
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type'   => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',

'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'or',
        array(
        'key'=> '1bb',
        'value' => array($from , $to),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE', 
        ),

        array(
        'key'=> '1aa',
        'value' => array($from , $to),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'DATE', 
        ),
    ),
);
echo count( get_posts( $args ) );
?>
```

Thank you.

The following is additional code that I tried to prevent from double counting.
Its too long time to load, and can not use it.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'or',

        array(                        
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    array(
                    'key'=> '1aa',
                    'value' => array($from , $to),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    'inclusive' => 'true',
                    'type' => 'DATE', 
                    ),

                   array(
                    'key'     => '1bb',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                     ),
                ),
        ),

        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    array(
                    'key'=> '1bb',
                    'value' => array($from , $to),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    'inclusive' => 'true',
                    'type' => 'DATE', 
                    ),

                   array(
                    'key'     => '1aa',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                     ),
                ),
        ),

        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    array(
                    'key'=> '1bb',
                    'value' => array($from , $to),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    'inclusive' => 'true',
                    'type' => 'DATE', 
                    ),

                   array(
                    'key'     => '1aa',
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                     ),

                   array(
                    'key'     => '1bb',
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                     ),                     
                ),
        ),

),
```

Comment: have you tried with and instead of or in the relation?

Comment: Hi A Shah  Thank you for your comment.  I tried other code like additional one that I up now.  I can not imagine how I can avoid using 'or' in this case...

Comment: great post your answer with details so other can get to know when they have same issue.

Comment: Do you just need the count (number) or actual data?

Comment: Hi Johnny Tee  Thank you for your comment.  I use this $args for counting posts and caculating sales amount .